# i can't run my Github code on Spyder

Tags: python, github, anaconda, spyder, pythonpath

I want to run [this code on github](http://github.com/llazzaro/lsa_python) :

"Spyder 2.7", "anaconda2" "windows7" 64bits.

But i don't know how because it is on my desktop like folder. in this code they said to run it with nosetests. But i really don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run nosetests from spyder you'll have to run it from the command line. Assuming the cloned repo it's in a folder on your desktop called `master` open a command prompt (cmd) and type

```
cd Desktop\master
nosetests
```

If you want to run the code in Spyder, you can type `cd Desktop\master\lsa` into the Ipython console, and then `import lsa` to import the functions.